# Populating TAG page when using the kebab filter

Tags: templating, entry, tag

I have a page that displays entries based on a specific tag. It works well until I apply the [kebab filter.](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#kebab)

Here's my link to the page:

```
{% for tag in tag %}
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | kebab}}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

and my tags/tag.html page looks like this:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.name(tag).first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).order('title') %}
{% if entries | length %}
   {% for entry in entries %}
       Code here
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The page populates all entries regardless of the tag once I apply the kebab filter. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your link, change `{{ tag.title | kebab}}` to `{{ tag.slug }}`

Then on your tag.html page change your `tag` variable to this:

`{% set tag = craft.tags.slug( craft.request.segment(2) ).first() %}`

This is how I have it set up and works fine.

Edit: Forgot the route needed: Add this to your routes.php: `'tags/{slug}' => 'tags/tag',`